# Check chart properties using OpenXml

Tags: c#, charts, powerpoint, openxml, presentation

[image]I want to check if property `Switch Rows/Columns` is enabled or not in a bar chart, while reading it with `OpenXml`.

Comment: Can you please be more spezific or post the Code you came so far?

Comment: I cant see any Screen shot

Comment: @Hille.. I have attached screenshot. Please take a look.

Comment: Sry but i cant help you there, but maybe someone else can help you now :)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Have you already tried to use the `OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool` to find out what you need to change in the file? (you could do this by creating 2 files, 1 file with the option enabled and 1 file with the option disabled, and then compare those 2 files in the `OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool` to find any differences)

Comment: @bassfader I have done that and found some difference but nothing related to this property.

       <c:f>
        Sheet1!$A$2
       </c:f>

another file
       <c:f>
        Sheet1!$B$1
       </c:f>

Comment: @bassfader it's just showing column reference but using that I can not able to find these are switched or not